# Array assignment to null

Tags: php, arrays

The following

```
$array = null;
$array['xxx'] = 12;
\var_dump($array);
```

Will output

```
array (size=1)
    'xxx' => int 12
```

Why? Any way to have PHP report these as errors?

Comment: What error are you expecting?

Comment: This would be the expected output for what you have written.  Did you mean to put that back slash before the var_dump?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an error reporting set to [E_NOTICE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) would cause a notice to be thrown - I might be wrong though. **Edit**: I can confirm that this does **NOT** throw a notice. Even just `$foo['bar'] = true; var_dump($foo);` seem to work.

Comment: There's no error with type casting there if that's what you're asking.

Comment: [Check this part of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) - It's working as designed. `If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array. This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and [] may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to initialize variable by a direct assignment.`

Comment: @h2ooooooo ic, thanks for the info, can you post your two comments as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @srcspider You should accept MitchS's answer, as he pretty much said the same thing without the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array['xxx'] = 12;
```

Where `$array` is null/undefined, the above assignment will create the array and is equivalent to:

```
$array = array('xxx' => 12);
```